# How do I convert svn:external files to files that can be added?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Say I have a project that uses external dependencies which are imported from another repository using svn:externals. 
When creating a TAG, I don't want it to depend on an external repository.
What is the easiest way to commit a TAG including the real code instead of a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you modify the external dependency to refer to a specific revision of the external library or you put a copy of that into your own repository. For the latter, read about [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s04.html).

Comment: The suggestion about vendor branches seems quite usefull! I'll further look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your reasoning for not depending on an external repository, [pegging of externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) may be appropriate. This means the code on the tag will not be updated from the external source when doing svn update, unless you specifically edit the externals definition and increase the version number.